# Unique document number for the month

Tags: php, mysql, invoice

I need to create an invoice number in format:

```
CONSTANT_STRING/%d/mm/yyyy
```

mm - Month (two digits)
yyyy - Year

Now, the **%d** is the number of the invoice in the specific month. Another words, this number is reseted every month.

Now I am checking in database what is the highest number in current month. Then after its incrementation I am saving the row.

I need the whole number to be unique. However, it sometimes happens that it is being duplicated (two users save in the same time).

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have a unique_identifier on that table? can't you use that? or perhaps a timestamp to figure out which entry came first?

Comment: which database engine are you using for your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a unique index on the field and catch the database error when trying to save the second instance. Also, defer getting the value until the last possible moment.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, which blocks the row until you update it, but can cause deadlocks with a serios multitasking application.

The best way is to fetch the number and increment it in a transaction and then start the work.
This way, the row is not locked for long.

Look into `BEGIN WORK` and `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the primary key (preferably an `INT`) of the invoice table or assign a unique number to each invoice, e.g. via [`uniqid`](http://de3.php.net/uniqid).

PS. If you are using `uniqid`, you can increase the *uniqueness* by setting `more_entropy` parameter to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

set the id all in one query.

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (invoice_number) VALUES (CONCAT(\''.CONSTANT.'\', \'/\', (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS current_id FROM table WHERE MONTH(entry_date) = \''.date('n').'\' AND YEAR(entry_date) = \''.date('Y').'\'), \'/\', \''.date('m/Y').'\'))';
```